# list of folders to be included BY DEFAULT while compiling C++ files

Tags: visual-c++, build-process, compilation, cl.exe

HI All

I am using MS C++ compiler `cl.exe` at command line to build my projects. The list of directory that must be included with `/I` is huge. I don't want to include this big huge list for each file I need to compile.

Do you know a way to set the list of folders to be included by default so that these will not appear at the command line when building .cpp files? Does exist some environment variable for that or some configuration?

Thanks
EO

Answer (score 1):

Put the commands in a [response file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3te4xt0y.aspx):

> "A response file can contain any commands that you would specify on the command line."